# Update "progress bar" based on selection in Ractive

Tags: ractivejs

I am new to Ractive.js. What i am basically trying to achieve is that based on the id selection(from the combo box),update appropriate progress bar.

In below sample, there are two progress bars and 4 buttons(+25,+10,-25,-10).User can select any progressbar(say "first") and then press any buttons like +25 etc.When the user performs this action, appropriate progressbar should be updated(in this case "first" by say "25").

I have tried but am not sure how to select context based on progressbar selection.In my case,both progress bars get updated irrespective of what i have selected in select box. Please let me know how can i resolve this issue and also tell me if there is a way to clean the code(something like ng-repeat etc)

Please see the code in [See full code here....](http://jsfiddle.net/shenoyvnm/awh5v9p6/)

```
.progress-bar {
 position: relative;
 width: 200px;
 height: 40px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 }
.progress-bar-fill {
 height: inherit;
 background-color: orange;
}    

.progress-bar-fill-red {
height: inherit;
background-color: red;  
}
.progress-label {
position: relative;
top: 3px;
left: 5px;
color: #000;
}
input[type=range] {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
cursor: pointer;
/* essentially making range slider invisible */
opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here is to keep track of which progress bar is selected (which you're doing with the `selectedProgress` value), and use that to determine which value to update.

Another trick: any time you find yourself writing the same (or similar) code again and again, it's *usually* a sign that you can abstract something into a function or loop (the so-called Don't Repeat Yourself rule, or DRY). In this case, we can move the progress bars into a repeated section. Having done that, it makes more sense to keep the value of the progress bar in the same object as the name, like `{ name: 'first', value: 0 }`, because then, when we're iterating over the `progressbar` objects, we can just use `{{value}}` to refer to that progress bar's value, rather than having to retrieve the value from somewhere else.

By the same token we can avoid re-writing the logic that updates the value, by having a single function (let's call it `adjust`) and calling it directly from the template:

```js
var ractive = new Ractive({
  el: document.body,
  template: '#template',
  data: {
    progressbars: [
      // notice no `id` field – in the <select>, we can just
      // use the current index
      { name: 'first', value: 0 },
      { name: 'second', value: 0 }

      // and so on...
    ],
    amounts: [ +25, +10, -10, -25 ]
  },
  adjust: function ( d ) {
    var selected = this.get( 'selectedProgress' );
    if ( selected == null ) return;

    var keypath = 'progressbars[' + selected + '].value';
    this.add( keypath, d );
  }
});
```

```html
{{#each amounts}}
  <button disabled='{{selectedProgress == null}}' on-click='adjust(this)'>{{this > 0 ? '+' : ''}}{{this}}</button>
{{/each}}
```

Now, whenever the button (which is disabled if you haven't selected a progress bar) is clicked, the `adjust` function is called with the current amount in the `amounts` array (i.e. `this`).

All of which is easier to show than to describe, so here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rich_harris/k8vpcv27/

Comment: Thanks Ryan, But i have a question here. I have updated my jsfiddle based on your sample.I have added "setValue" method to check border cases i.e if value goes below 0,it remains 0% and not displayed in -ve value."SetValue" method just checks if value is less than 0 and returns "0" (if it's in negative). However, i want my setValue method to update "value" as well. Basically, I want "value" not to go below 0 too.I have updated my jsfiddle below

http://jsfiddle.net/shenoyvnm/awh5v9p6/4/

PS:Thanks for closing the question on github.I was not aware that both forums are managed by same people.

Comment: in order to fix it i have updated the code.
it still has "setValue" function.Along with it also updated "adjust" method.In this method i check if "keypath" value is less than 0 and set value accordingly. Please see code below. Is there a better way to do this.

http://jsfiddle.net/shenoyvnm/awh5v9p6/5/

Comment: You'd be better off doing the validation in the `adjust` function (i.e. `value = Math.max(0,this.get(keypath)+d); this.set(keypath, value)` – think of functions in the template as being *read-only*. That way you don't need the `setValue` function, and there's no danger of things getting out of sync between the model and the view